# ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset debugging help

Tags: ssh, putty

I am trying to use the ssh on my windows 10 machine to connect to my GoDaddy Cpanel server. My regular options of FileZilla, mobaxterm and putty are all broke. The only debugging method I have found has been what is listed below.

```
C:\Users\Joshua>ssh -v 107.180.12.188
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4
debug1: Connecting to 107.180.12.188 [107.180.12.188] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Joshua/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Joshua/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Joshua/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Joshua/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Joshua/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Joshua/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Joshua/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Joshua/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset
```

Comment: How old are you tools (Filezilla and others)?

Comment: All my tools are up to date. The problem started after the last windows 10 update.

Comment: You should have added that in the question. However I suspect your problem is a Windows related one and not Unix, and slightly out of topic here. Could it be due to this? https://twitter.com/Oddvarmoe/status/996177052599545857?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E996177052599545857&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bleepingcomputer.com%2Fnews%2Fmicrosoft%2Fwindows-10-openssh-client-installed-by-default-in-april-2018-update%2F

Comment: I didn't knew that windows had updated at the time of the first post. And as for the binaries... I have no idea how to interpret the information give to fix the problem.

Comment: Try to uninstall them as the twit says

Comment: Didn't work.... Thanks Rui for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you have miss-configured your server:
first check your /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny

```
root@host # grep sshd /etc/hosts.allow
sshd: ALL
```

or if you have set a public key on your server check them also - maybe it is faulty.

maybe your find more info on: http://edoceo.com/notabene/ssh-exchange-identification

Comment: Do I check that on a the server? I have a godaddy shared hosting plan...

Answer (score 0):

mate is the server listening on ipv4? if it's just v6, it'll reproduce your error

```
>netstat -apn | grep ":22"
```

```
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      4791/sshd
```

vs

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4791/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      4791/sshd
```